# Как разместить поля в таком порядке?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, регистрация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый вечер, хотел спросить, как разместить поля для ввода в таком порядке, как на фото? Что б именно было 3 колонки сверху (Название объекта -> дни и время работы -> длительность). А под этими 3 колонками две маленьких, но уже вряд (всего мест и стоимость). Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А зачем вы продублировали свой вопроc?

Comment: Я вошёл в аккаунт, сформулировал более чётче свой вопрос и обрезал картинку. На картинке теперь конкретно то, о чем я спрашиваю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, насколько я правильно понял по картинке, такое расположение можно реализовать через `grid`:

У Вас есть пять элементов: **"Название объекта"**, **"Дни и время работы"**, **"Длительность"**, **"Всего мест"** и **"Стоимость"**. Каждый из них оборачивайте в свой `div` и поместите их в какой-то родительский тэг `div`, типа "обертки".

И его сделайте grid-контейнером, прописав в свойствах:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 45% 35% 20%; //тут Ваши значения ширины колонок по макету
grid-template-rows: 80% 20%; //тут Ваши значения высоты строк по макету
```